# How to keep Gmsh mesh in the bounding curves?

Tags: mesh, gmsh

i am quite a beginner in Gmsh and am trying to create a mesh for hydrodynamic simulation from coastlines. I used splines for the complex coastline for simplicity, but the produced mesh crossed over the coastlines. What should i do to make the mesh not cross over the bounding curves?

Image for reference

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your mesh is simply to coarse in the moment. The points of each Triangle in the mesh lie on the real geometry/coastline but the edges are linearly connected and do not care about the geometry.

In order to refine the mesh you might try to press `Mesh`->`Refine by Splitting` a couple of times and see split the few current cells. The mesh should get finer and should not violate the geometry boarder by as much as right now.

BUT by this you'll only make the "issue" less obvious to see. On a smaller scale you will always see mesh cells that are partly "outside" the geometry borders. You cannot prevent this with concave meshes like the one you have here. If you have s.th. convex like a circle all elements will strictly lie inside the geometry border.

So as a first step, make a finer mesh until you are satisfied with the match between geometry and mesh.